# Django Rest Framework сериалайзер для many-to-many связи с этой же моделью через through

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Код реализует отношение дружбы, есть модель Profile, в ней есть поле friends, указывающее на список друзей - тех же моделей Profile, связь происходить через модель FriendshipRequest. С помощью сериалайзера поле friends преобразуется в список id друзей пользователя. Нельзя ли сделать, чтобы в friends был список имён друзей пользователя?

То есть сейчас поле выглядит так:

```
"friends": [
    id_1,
    id_2,
    ...,
    id_n          
]
```

А мне хотелось бы, чтобы оно отображалось таким образом:

```
"friends": [
    first_name_1,
    first_name_2,
    ...,
    first_name_n          
]
```

Код:

## models.py

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, default='Name')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, default='Surname')
    friends = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False, 
        through='FriendshipRequest', through_fields=('sender', 'receiver'))
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars', default='avatars/default.jpg')
    header = models.ImageField(upload_to='headers', default='headers/default.jpg')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="")


class FriendshipRequest(models.Model):
    REQUESTED = 'REQUESTED'
    ACCEPTED = 'ACCEPTED'
    REJECTED = 'REJECTED'

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (REQUESTED, 'requested'),
        (ACCEPTED, 'accepted'),
        (REJECTED, 'rejected'),
    )

    status = models.TextField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=REQUESTED)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sender')
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='receiver')
```

## serializers.py

```py
class FriendshipRequestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sender = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    receiver = serializers.StringRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = FriendshipRequest
        fields = '__all__'


class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   sclass Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ModelSerializer` автоматически определяет набор полей и для отношений ManyToMany используется `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`, т.е. получится следующее:

```
ProfileSerializer():
    id = IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
    first_name = CharField(max_length=25, required=False)
    last_name = CharField(max_length=25, required=False)
    avatar = ImageField(max_length=100, required=False)
    header = ImageField(max_length=100, required=False)
    status = CharField(max_length=20, required=False)
    friends = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
```

Есть несколько вариантов чтобы изменить поведение по умолчанию. 
Один из самых простых:
  добавляем для модели `Profile` строковое представление переопределив метод `__str__`:

```
  class Profile(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, default='Name')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, default='Surname')
    friends = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False,
                                     through='FriendshipRequest', through_fields=('sender', 'receiver'))
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars', default='avatars/default.jpg')
    header = models.ImageField(upload_to='headers', default='headers/default.jpg')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

в сериализаторе явно указываем класс для поля `friends`:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    friends = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'avatar', 'header', 'status', 'friends')
```